# How do I convert my functions to a class?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to get into the world of OOP and therefore building my first class out of some file handler functions. I am having a hard time understanding the whole idea of objects and methods, and I am not quite sure if I did it the right way, though the output is as expected.

I would appreciate your help with the following example. How could I add a method to it the right way?

**class.File.php**

```
class File {

    public $file = '';
    public $data = '';

    public function __construct($file = '') {
        $this->file = $file;
    }


    function put($create = false) {
        // Check if file is writeable and put content, won't create new file unsless $create is set to true
        if($create == false) {
            is_writable($this->file) ? file_put_contents($this->file, $this->data, LOCK_EX) : exit;
        } else {
            file_put_contents($this->file, $this->data);
        }   
    }
}
```

**example call**

```
$f = new File();
$f->file = "/www/htdocs/somehost/folder/data/helloworld.txt";
$f->data = "Hello world";
$f->put('true');
```

Comment: _"How could I add a method to it?"_ - how do you mean - syntax-wise? You seem to know that already. So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Although you might rather want to pass your two "parameters" (`file`, which should perhaps rather be `name`, and `data`) to the constructor and assign them in there. And make the properties non-public instead. You might want to keep a method to set data to something else perhaps, if you also want to be able to use this object to modify existing files later on. `file_put` is a rather unlucky method name here IMHO. We know we are dealing with a File object already - so I would name the method just `put`, or maybe rather `save`.

Comment: I think that's the point I am missing. I didn't understand yet how to make the properties non-public but passing them to constructor. Sorry if my question was misleading.

Comment: Well you passed an optional $file parameter already, so you could do that with data as well. If the file name is not supposed to be changable later on for an existing object, make $file a mandatory parameter for the constructor. And you don't need to call setFile in the constructor - you are inside the class, so you have access to all properties regardless of their visibility, so `$this->file = ...` will do.

Comment: And if you want to get fancier, you could make the constructor check if the file already exists, and if so read its content into $data automatically. The setData method (property is non-public now, so you're gonna need one, if you want to be able to manipulate data after construction) could get a parameter added to tell it whether to replace or append to the data, and put/save whether to replace an existing file automatically, or maybe throw an exception instead if not specifically instructed to overwrite ...

Comment: @GerritFries what's the responsibility/purpose of the class?

Comment: Probably an unfortunate choice on your part choosing a file class.  You might want to look at the `splfileobject` out of curiosity. See: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

Answer (score 2):

Object is the concrete entity of the real world. That has properties and behaviour (methods).

What are the properties of the concrete file? It is a name, permissions, a date of creation, etc. All properties should be hidden from real world.

What behaviour can the file have? Read content, rewrite content, append content, rename, delete, change permissions, etc. All that you do with the file. Note it is better to have two methods "rewrite content" and "append content" than one "put" with arguments. Because these are different actions on the file.

So let's write the class File.

```
class File
{
    private $name;
    private $permissions;

    // name and permissions are mandatory because file cannot exist without these properties
    public function __construct($name, $permissions)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->permissions = $permissions;
    }

    public function read()
    {
        // you can check if the file exists
        return file_get_contents($this->name);
    }

    // may also named `put`
    public function write($content)
    {
        file_put_contents($this->name, $content);
    }

    public function append($content)
    {
        file_put_contents($this->name, $content, FILE_APPEND);
    }

    public function rename($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Any checks (if file exists, if file is writeble) is concrete implementation, not about OOP.

PS
You can read this article http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html about getters and setters.

Comment: A rename method name is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Agree with @Progrock, a better naming would be `renameTo($name)` and then the method should actually rename the file.

Comment: On the other hand, you might be interested in the current name and permissions, so accessors `name()` and `permissions()` aren't actually that bad.